# USB to Serial driver for windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, serial-port

When I connect ingenico terminal with USB cable to my windows 7 laptop, there is new COM port in device manager and I can use it. Properties show that serial port uses sagem monetel driver. I do not remember how I installed it and I did not google any trustworthy site to download the driver, as sagem was acquired by Ingenico.

My foreign collegue needs to repeat my setup, but when he plugs the terminal to USB port, there is no serial port. Where can he download some driver to make USB device appear as serial port?

Comment: More information is required. Have you checked the Ingenico website for the driver?   The cable itself should handle this since its USB.

Comment: There is no public download on their site.

Comment: I think there isn't a lot of chips for bridging USB to Serial. Maybe you can try with this one: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm It's s shoot in the dark, of course. But maybe you are lucky.

Comment: just looked up virtual rs232   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port

Comment: @barlop - good point, Eterlogic is on my computer already. Its installation might provide the driver. I forwarded link and we will see.

Comment: No, it did not help either.